# How can i put loop and get values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var data={ 
    Data: { 
        name: 'aaaa',
        number: '0003'
    },
    values: { 
        val: '-20.00',
        rate: '22047' 
    },
    user: [ '6|1|5', '10|1|15' ] 
};

console.log(data);
console.log(data.user.length);
for(var i=0;i<data.user.length;i++) {
    console.log(data.user[i]);
}
</script>
```

Above is my code i want to put loop and get values like this

this is my data `user: [ '6|1|5', '10|1|15' ]`

but i want to get like this:

- userid - 6
- roolno - 1
- rank   - 5

  ---
- userid - 10
- roolno - 1
- rank   - 15

how can i do this any one help me out ?

Comment: You'd have to do two for loops. One to get the first object, then the second loop to loop through each thing you want ( userid, roolno, rank)

Comment: how can i do this help me out @D

Answer (score 5):

A simple map would do it ([see plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uYSYxxKat5IDYSOtKiSV?p=preview)):

```
data.user.map(function(x) { 
    var parts = x.split('|');
    return {
        userid: parts[0],
        roolno: parts[1],
        rank: parts[2]
    };
});
```

This would return you:

```
[
    {
        userid: 1,
        roolno: 1,
        rank: 5
    },
    {
        userid: 10,
        roolno: 1,
        rank: 15
    },
]
```